# Google Drive API return invalidSharingRequest when trying to share folder using service account

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I am trying to share a folder using service account through Google API Drive using the following code:

```py
import apiclient
import httplib2
from googleapiclient import discovery
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

CREDENTIALS_FILE = 'creds.json'

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    CREDENTIALS_FILE,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
)
httpAuth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=httpAuth)

def share_file(file_id, user_email):
    """Batch permission modification.
    Args:
        file_id: file Id
        user_email: User ID
    Prints modified permissions
    """
    ids = []
    file_id = file_id

    def callback(request_id, response, exception):
        if exception:
            # Handle error
            print(exception)
        else:
            print(f'Request_Id: {request_id}')
            print(F'Permission Id: {response.get("id")}')
            ids.append(response.get('id'))

    batch = DRIVE.new_batch_http_request(callback=callback)
    user_permission = {
        'type': 'user',
        'role': 'commenter',
        'emailAddress': user_email,
        'supportsAllDrives': True
    }
    batch.add(DRIVE.permissions().create(fileId=file_id,
                                         body=user_permission,
                                         fields='id'
                                         ))
    batch.execute()

    return ids
```

And in result i get: *Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'invalidSharingRequest', 'message': 'Bad Request. User message: "You cannot share this item because it has been flagged as inappropriate."'}]"*

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Most likely this file `has been flagged as inappropriate`, as the error says. Are you able to share it if you try doing it via user-interface? How and where was this file created, and what kind of file is this?

Comment: @lamblichus It's just an empty folder. I've tried via user interface - it works. Also i tried to use google api via my personal account explorer and it worked. So I have an assumption that the service account is missing some settings

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is the reason behind the error you're getting, you are using a [deprecated library](https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Consider using [google-auth](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/master/) instead (see [google.oauth2.service_account module](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/master/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html#module-google.oauth2.service_account)).